# Using VBA code to fill in data in Word from Excel. It worked for one test customer but not others when I added data and I don't understand why

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to use VBA code to extract data from a master Excel sheet into a Word document that will have a drop down list of customers at the start, and then have certain parts of the rest of it change to data dependent on that customer.

I found an example one that I copied and altered to suit my needs that is working (sort of), but I don't understand enough about why it works to get it right. When I started making it I only had data on one customer so used that info to test it as I went. However, when I filled in some data for other customers I found that it didn't work for them, only the first one. I also noticed that when I added another column to the Excel sheet, it tells me the subscript is out of range. That's lead me to believe that the code is getting the data from an out-of-date Excel sheet, and therefore not including the updated version, despite my best efforts to get it to use a new one. I hope this could be helped with some minor tweaking to my code where perhaps there is a specified range of columns that I've exceeded.

The code I used:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal oCC As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim arrData() As String
Dim strData As String
Dim lngIndex As Long
  Select Case oCC.Title
    Case "CC Conditional Dropdown List"
      With oCC
        If Not .ShowingPlaceholderText Then

          For lngIndex = 1 To .DropdownListEntries.Count
            If .Range.Text = .DropdownListEntries.Item(lngIndex) Then
              strData = .DropdownListEntries.Item(lngIndex).Value
              .Type = wdContentControlText
              .Range.Text = strData
              .Type = wdContentControlDropdownList
              Exit For
            End If
          Next lngIndex
        End If
      End With
     Case "Name"
      If Not oCC.ShowingPlaceholderText Then

        For lngIndex = 1 To oCC.DropdownListEntries.Count
          If oCC.Range.Text = oCC.DropdownListEntries.Item(lngIndex) Then

            arrData = Split(oCC.DropdownListEntries.Item(lngIndex).Value, "|")
            Exit For
          End If
        Next lngIndex

        With oCC
          .Type = wdContentControlText
          .Range.Text = arrData(0)
          .Type = wdContentControlDropdownList
        End With

        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AM").Item(1).Range.Text = Replace(arrData(1), "~", Chr(11))
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("CSA").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(2)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Contract").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(3)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Renewal").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(4)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("CurrentHR").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(5)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("RUG").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(6)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("eRMI").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(7)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("PurchasedHRSCBS").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(8)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("PurchasedMODAMEJpeRMALOD").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(9)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ActualHRSCBS").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(10)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ActualMODAM").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(11)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ActualER").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(12)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ActualEJp").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(13)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ActualMedApp").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(14)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ActualLoD").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(15)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ERattainmentCons").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(16)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ERattainmentnon-Cons").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(17)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ERattainmentNwBN").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(18)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ERattainmentWBN").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(19)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ERattainmentAHPs").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(20)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ERattainmentPharm").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(21)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("eJPAttainmentCons").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(22)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("eJPAttainmentNonCons").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(23)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("eJPAttainmentNWBN").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(24)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("eJPAttainmentAHPs").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(25)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("eJPAttainmentPharma").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(26)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHRPropSent").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(27)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHmPropSent").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(28)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHRPropReturned").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(29)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHMPropReturned").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(30)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHRcourses").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(31)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHMcourses").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(32)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHREntit").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(33)
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHMEntit").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(34)

      Else

        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AM").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("CSA").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Contract").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Renewal").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("CurrentHR").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("RUG").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("eRMI").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("PurchasedHRSCBS").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("PurchasedMODAMEJpeRMALOD").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ActualHRSCBS").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ActualMODAM").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ActualER").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ActualEJp").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ActualMedApp").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ActualLoD").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ERattainmentCons").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ERattainmentnon-Cons").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ERattainmentNwBN").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ERattainmentWBN").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ERattainmentAHPs").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ERattainmentPharm").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("eJPAttainmentCons").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("eJPAttainmentNonCons").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("eJPAttainmentNWBN").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("eJPAttainmentAHPs").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("eJPAttainmentPharma").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHRPropSent").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHmPropSent").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHRPropReturned").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHMPropReturned").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHRcourses").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHMcourses").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHMEntit").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHREntit").Item(1).Range.Text = vbNullString

      End If
    Case Else
  End Select
lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub
End Sub
Sub Document_Open()
Dim strWorkbook As String, strColumnData As String
Dim lngIndex As Long, lngRowIndex As Long, lngColIndex As Long
Dim arrData As Variant
Dim oCC As ContentControl, oFF As FormField, oCtrl As Control
Dim bReprotect As Boolean
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  strWorkbook = ThisDocument.Path & "\Excel Data Store.xlsx"
  If Dir(strWorkbook) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Cannot find the designated workbook: " & strWorkbook, vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
  arrData = fcnExcelDataToArray(strWorkbook, "Simple List")
  Set oCC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("CC Dropdown List").Item(1)
  If oCC.DropdownListEntries.Item(1).Value = vbNullString Then
    For lngIndex = oCC.DropdownListEntries.Count To 2 Step -1
      oCC.DropdownListEntries.Item(lngIndex).Delete
    Next lngIndex
  Else
    oCC.DropdownListEntries.Clear
  End If
  For lngRowIndex = 0 To UBound(arrData, 2)
    oCC.DropdownListEntries.Add arrData(0, lngRowIndex), arrData(0, lngRowIndex)
  Next
  Set oFF = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Formfield_DD_List")
  bReprotect = False
  If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
    ActiveDocument.Unprotect
    bReprotect = True
  End If
  oFF.DropDown.ListEntries.Clear
  For lngRowIndex = 0 To UBound(arrData, 2)
    oFF.DropDown.ListEntries.Add arrData(0, lngRowIndex)
  Next
  If bReprotect Then ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, True
  With ActiveX_ComboBox
    .Clear
    .AddItem "        "
    For lngRowIndex = 0 To UBound(arrData, 2)
     .AddItem arrData(0, lngRowIndex)
    Next
    .MatchRequired = True
    .Style = fmStyleDropDownList
  End With

  arrData = fcnExcelDataToArray(strWorkbook, "Simple Conditional List")
  Set oCC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("CC Conditional Dropdown List").Item(1)

  If oCC.DropdownListEntries.Item(1).Value = vbNullString Then

    For lngIndex = oCC.DropdownListEntries.Count To 2 Step -1
      oCC.DropdownListEntries.Item(lngIndex).Delete
    Next lngIndex
  Else

    oCC.DropdownListEntries.Clear
  End If
  For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(arrData, 2)
    oCC.DropdownListEntries.Add arrData(0, lngIndex), arrData(1, lngIndex)
  Next
  arrData = fcnExcelDataToArray(strWorkbook, "Advanced Conditional List")
  Set oCC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Name").Item(1)
  If oCC.DropdownListEntries.Item(1).Value = vbNullString Then
    For lngIndex = oCC.DropdownListEntries.Count To 2 Step -1
      oCC.DropdownListEntries.Item(lngIndex).Delete
    Next lngIndex
  Else
    oCC.DropdownListEntries.Clear
  End If
  For lngRowIndex = 0 To UBound(arrData, 2)

    strColumnData = vbNullString
    For lngColIndex = 1 To UBound(arrData, 1)
      strColumnData = strColumnData & "|" & arrData(lngColIndex, lngRowIndex)
    Next lngColIndex
    strColumnData = Right(strColumnData, Len(strColumnData) - 1)
    oCC.DropdownListEntries.Add arrData(0, lngRowIndex), strColumnData
  Next
lbl_Exit:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Exit Sub
End Sub
Private Function fcnExcelDataToArray(strWorkbook As String, _
                                     Optional strRange As String = "Sheet1", _
                                     Optional bIsSheet As Boolean = True, _
                                     Optional bHeaderRow As Boolean = True) As Variant

Dim oRS As Object, oConn As Object
Dim lngRows As Long
Dim strHeaderYES_NO As String
  strHeaderYES_NO = "YES"
  If Not bHeaderRow Then strHeaderYES_NO = "NO"
  If bIsSheet Then strRange = strRange & "$]" Else strRange = strRange & "]"
  Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  oConn.Open ConnectionString:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & strWorkbook & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=" & strHeaderYES_NO & """;"
  Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  oRS.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & strRange, oConn, 2, 1
  With oRS
    .MoveLast
    lngRows = .RecordCount
    .MoveFirst
  End With
  fcnExcelDataToArray = oRS.GetRows(lngRows)
lbl_Exit:
  If oRS.State = 1 Then oRS.Close
  Set oRS = Nothing
  If oConn.State = 1 Then oConn.Close
  Set oConn = Nothing
  Exit Function
End Function
```

I expect data dependant on a customer selected from a dropdown list to be extracted from an Excel document and filled into a Word document.

Am getting the error code:

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

on the line:

```
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("AcademyHMEntit").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(34)
```

after adding in a column to the master Excel sheet so believe the VBA is trying to use an out of date version of the master Excel sheet.

Screenshot of the content controls below with the customer name being the dropdown list and the bits in yellow as content dependant on it

[image]

Comment: Try adding `Debug.Print UBound(arrData,1), UBound(arrData,2)` right before the line that errors, and see what output you get in the Immediate pane.

Comment: It's still coming up at [out of range](https://imgur.com/fVzTDDl)

Comment: Sorry, just `Debug.Print UBound(arrData)` - missed it's a single-dimension array

Comment: It's still coming up as out of range so I tried redoing the whole thing from the beginning again and it still is coming up. I think it's coming from somewhere else in the code. When I put in data for other customers, even for the columns that worked for the first customer, it still uses the original version of the excel sheet where they were blank, so the output from the dropdown list comes out blank. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: If you're getting the wrong data then it's likely your code is opening the wrong file or reading from the wrong sheet.  Also - *what is the output* from the Print statement - that's not a "fix", it's meant to tell you something.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought but I tried renaming it to something completely different (making sure the vba code changed to reflect that) and even deleted all versions of it but it still brings back the out of date version. It still brings back the correct data for the first customer that I was testing it on as I made it (but doesn't update if I change the data), and the list of customers is still accurate so it can't be drawing data from a completely incorrect file. Is there anything in my code that you can see causing the issue?

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry I didn't notice the bit at the end about the print statement. I was getting an error message that at first thought was from a change I had made elsewhere but I just realised it may be the output I was getting. I'm getting [this](https://imgur.com/bFsn0p4) error message. Is that the output you meant or is it unrelated?